# How should I construct an std::array<T, k> from a U with sizeof(U) = k * sizeof(T)?

Tags: templates, c++11, constructor, stdarray

I want to represent a single variable of type U as an array of type-T elements, for use *at compile time*. sizeof(T) divides sizeof(U) perfectly, so letting k = sizeof(U)/sizeof(T) it should be an `std::array<T, k>`.

Problem is, how do I construct it (again, at compile time)? Can/should I use casting, i.e.

```
* (reinterpret_cast<std::array<T,k> *>(&my_u))
```

or maybe some sort of recursive function call setting its elements? Or is there some better/nicer way?

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: Sound alot like a bitfield or perhaps even a union.

Comment: Not possible; you can't `reinterpret_cast` at compile time.

Comment: @GManNickG: For the sake of discussion, suppose I have some constexpr function which takes elements of type T, and I want to apply it to arbitrary-sized types (and I can't just rewrite that function).

Comment: @ecatmur: Ok, hence my question regarding a better alternative. It's definitely doable with recursion.

Comment: @einpoklum: Sorry, this is just too vague to give a meaningful answer. In general, you aren't going to be able to cast pointers across types in a constexpr.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to alias value representations is almost always to use `memcpy`:

```
std::array<T, k> my_t;
static_assert(sizeof(my_t) == sizeof(my_u), "!!");
std::memcpy(my_t.data(), &my_u, sizeof(my_u));
```

There is no "nicer" way, as you will need to use `memcpy` at some point to bypass strict aliasing restrictions (unless `T` is a narrow character type).

At compile time, this is in general impossible as the C++ Standard does not e.g. describe the layout of bits within floating-point types, or whether integral types are little-, big- or mixed-endian. This may be possible in some restricted instances, but you will not be able to use `memcpy` or `reinterpret_cast`, so will have to write type-specific code to access the members of `U` individually.

The best way to structure your code might be to write a collection of functions extracting values of type `T` from a value of type `U` at a specific offset:

```
constexpr T getValueOfTAtOffset(U u, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>) { ... }
constexpr T getValueOfTAtOffset(U u, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1>) { ... }
// ...
```

You would then call them using an `index_sequence` template inference:

```
template<std::size_t... I>
constexpr std::array<T, sizeof...(I)> asArrayOfTImpl(U u, std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, I...>) {
    return {getValueOfTAtOffset(u, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>{})};
}
constexpr std::array<T, k> asArrayOfT(U u) {
    return asArrayOfTImpl(u, std::make_index_sequence<k>{});
}
```

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't, but assume it's non-portable machine-dependent code and I do know the bit layout and endianness.

Comment: @einpoklum and it's `constexpr`? What's the signature?

Comment: What is 'it' in your last comment? If you mean the function which takes elements of type T - no, it's not constexpr, and actually it's not a function but something else; the thing is I can only use constexpr code since it's not your standard memory model, there's no memcpy() per se, and almost all of the constexpr code has to end up being optimized away.

Answer (score 0):

C++ (and C) has a feature known as strict aliasing.

Strict aliasing states that a pointer to `T` and a pointer to `U` are never pointers to the same data.

One reason behind this rule is that it permits a whole bunch of optimizations.  If you have a `int` and you dereference an `short*` and modify it, you *know* that the `int` was not modified without having to chase pointers.

Which means you can only reinterpret cast an `X*` to a `Y*` *if the pointer was originally actually a `Y*`*, **or** one of the execptions apply.

These exceptions include `Y` being a `char` type, or the layout-compatibility guarantees that basically talk about one structure being a prefix of another in certain standard layout cases.

In the general case, these do not apply.  So you must either seek out one of these exceptions, or use `memcpy` to marshall your data through one of these exceptions, to be standard-compliant.

The risk here is that aggressive compiler optmizations can significantly change the apparent meaning of your code when faced with blatant undefined behavior.  Even if you test it and it works, the next compiler version is justified in making your code break in various and sundry ways, or an innocuous compiler option flag, or anything else.

One option you can do is create a `union`.  But even there, access of the "wrong" part of the union is undefined behavior, barring standard layout guarantees.

A more specific set of information about your data might actually provide a way around it -- possibly you are satisfying the standard layout guarantees, for example -- but they are easy to break.